# Remove central noise from image

Tags: python, image, png, noise

I'm working with biologists, who are imaging DNA strands under a microscope, giving greyscale PNGs. Depending on the experiment, there can be a lot of background noise. On the ones where there is quite little, a simple threshold for pixel intensity is generally enough to remove it. However for some, it's not so simple.

[image: DNA lines on noisy background]

(not sure why it's uploading as jpg - [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yANfVlahYPouHLc_OQGmpkCVW-nM7ow8/view?usp=sharing) should let you download it as PNG)

When I do apply a threshold for pixel intensity, I get this result:

[image: Same DNA lines, but with a less noisy background]

If I raise the threshold any more, I'll start to lose the pixels at the edges of the image that aren't very bright.

The noise seems to follow a gaussian distribution based on its location within the image, probably due to the light source of the microscope. What's the best way to compare pixels to the local background noise? Can I integrate the noise distribution?

For the moment I've been using `imageio.v3` in python3 for basic pixel manipulation, but I'm open to suggestions.

EDIT: I tried to use histogram equalisation, but it doesn't *quite* seem to be what I'm looking for...

[image: DNA lines after histogram equalisation]

Comment: It looks to me more like vignetting from the optics with the centre of the field being somewhat brighter than the edges. Flat fielding on the background first might help a lot. Astronomers do it all the time since sky brightness has similar nuisance properties.  Also using some form of greedy histogram equalisation may reveal a lot more fine detail in the shadows without being quite so brutal as hard thresholding.

Comment: @MartinBrown I tried histogram equalisation using this tutorial https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html but it doesn't seem to be adapted to my scenario. Do you know where I could find info on flat field correction or vignette correction?

Comment: Astronomical processing software usually  has it in professional and amateur alike (although they have the option of doing a flat field correction too). Basically you delete all the recognisable signal (stars leaving just the sky background) and then fit a smooth surface to what's left  Google with "vignetting correction processing astronomy" should get you several plausible variations on the theme. Some might even be able to handle your images as if they were astronomical ones (ie mostly black with stars or in your case streaks and lines). BTW what are the 3 fuzzy brighter dot artefacts?

Comment: @MartinBrown I'll look into it, thanks! I suspect those dots are fingerprints on the gel used to suspend the DNA, but it could be anything. One of the experiments requires using a buffer solution that is slightly autofluorescent at the same wavelength as the DNA probe (which is where the strong bg noise comes from), so basically any imperfection in the gel will show up like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what result you want so I am working somewhat in the dark. I suspect you want a *"Local Area Threshold"* - see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing)#Global_vs_local_thresholding). Also referred to as *"Adaptive Threshold"*.

It is available, or can be achieved in many image processing packages, but for brevity and until I (or others) better understand what you want as a result, I will just demonstrate with **ImageMagick** which is free and can be installed on macOS, Linux and Windows. The command is [-lat](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#lat) which means *"Local Area Threshold"*.

So, the syntax to highlight in white any pixel that is more than 2% brighter than the surrounding local area of 80x80 is as follows:

```
magick image.png -alpha off -lat 80x80+2% result.png
```

[image]

If you want any pixel more than 2% brighter than its surrounding 10x10 neighbourhood, use:

```
magick image.png -alpha off -lat 10x10+2% result.png
```

[image]

---

Note that I used `-alpha off` because your image has a superfluous alpha channel I wanted to discard.

---

Using **OpenCV** you'll get something vaguely similar with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2 as cv

# Load image as greyscale
im = cv.imread('image.png', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Local area is 49x49, and pixel must be 15 above threshold to show in output
thMean = cv.adaptiveThreshold(im,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv.THRESH_BINARY,49,-15)
cv.imwrite('result-mean.png', thMean)

# Local area is 29x29, and pixel must be 10 above threshold to show in output
thGauss = cv.adaptiveThreshold(im,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv.THRESH_BINARY,29,-10)
cv.imwrite('result-Gauss.png', thGauss)
```

Comment: That... is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much! I'll try out the OpenCV implementation when I have time (probably next week, this is a side project), and I'll accept your answer then if everything runs smoothly. How does the 80*80+2% look so clean??